# Prove $n_1 \times n_2 = K \sqrt{g} n$

Tags: differential-geometry

This is an excerise from Millman Parker
's Elements of Differential geometry.

> Let $M $ be a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ parametrized by a function $x:U \to \mathbb R^3$ with $U \subset \mathbb R^2$. Let x_i be the $i $th partial derivative of $x $. Let $n 
> = \frac {x_1 × x_2}{|x_1 × x_2|} $ . Let $n_i $ be its $i $th partial derivative. Prove $n_1 \times n_2 = K \sqrt{g} \ n$, where $K=K_1K_2$ is the gaussian curvature,
> $\sqrt{g}=[x_1,x_2,n] = |x_1 × x_2|$.

We know $n|n_1 × n_2|
= n_1 × n_2$.

How is $K$ related to $n$ or $g$?

Comment: What are $x_1$, $x_2$, $n_1$, $n_2$, $K_1$, $K_2$, $G$ ?  This question looks intriguing but is hard to decipher without definitions of the variables involved.  Cheers!

Comment: $x_1$ is the partial of x(u,v) (a curve on a surface) w.r.t. u and $x_2$ is the partial w.r.t. v. $n_1$ is the partial of the normal of x w.r.t to first variable and similarly $n_2$. $K_1$ and $K_2$ are the eigenvalues of the $L$ matrix which is the weingarten map

Comment: @RobertLewis forgot to tag

Comment: What is this $G$ that you want to relate $K$ to?

Comment: g is the metric tensor matrix @user10354138

Comment: No!  There is the big $G$ in your last sentence "How is K related to n or G?"

Comment: oh that was a mistake sorry I meant little g!!!